# progress bar with percentage complete in framework 2.0 and asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i am developing application in asp.net 2.0 and c# where i am uploading file on server, while uploading file i want to show progress bar showing in percentage of upload completed,
Can any one please help me or suggest me  how can i do this in asp.net 2.0

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `AjaxFileUpload` control in the ***Asp.Net Ajax control toolkit***. It supports async file uploading and will display a progress bar in browsers that supports the HTML5 File API (not IE9 unfortunately).

Anyway, instead of me repeating what's on the page, [go have a look yourself](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx).

**Edit:** Oops, just realized that you wrote you are using .Net 2.0. I think the Ajax control toolkit needs at least .Net 3.5 nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this kind of stuff.. 
if you want to add this on web site.

then you need to:

1) add reference(System.Windows.Forms) in solution

2)Then add line:

```
        System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar progressbar1;
        progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar1.Maximum = 2000;
        for (int i = 0; i < progressBar1.Maximum; i++)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = i;
        }
```

Comment: yup ajax toolkit is not supported in 2.0. So you need to try on windows forms progress bar.